# Cupped fingejointed hardwood Birch panel

Tags: wood-movement, hardwood

I'm in the process of building myself a workbench. Up until now, I've been using the floor as my workbench.

I ordered an untreated, but planed fingerjointed hardwoord Beech counter to serve as my countertop (2m x 1m ~ 6ft by 3ft).
When it arrived it was quite cupped, both in width as well as in length.

When I asked the supplier about this, they told me to leave it for 24h on either side and it should straighten itself. I tried that, but it's still very much cupped in either direction.

I could attach it to the bottom of the workbench and leave some space in the bolts to allow for movement, but I'm not sure I want to be dealing with this as my workbench top.

What are some other things I could do to improve this board?

Needless to say, I'm a beginning woodworker and don't have a planer nor a jointer, nor will I get one anytime soon (and especially not one that allows for this size)

Comment: I'd email the supplier some pictures and ask them what method of return shipment they're paying for, then find a new supplier.

Comment: If this is a moisture-related issue (such as you get if you leave a freshly-planed board flat on the workbench overnight, or store a panel hard up against a garage wall) then drying could sort it out. You just need to dry it evenly, e.g. propped up *on edge* to allow air equal access to either side of the panel. If after some days like this it is not flat then absolutely seek a return as per @FreeMan's Comment above, explaining how you tried to dry it and that it was unsuccessful.... and by all means tell them how much bow/cupping it still has to give them a realistic idea of how bad it is.

Comment: Yeah, I left it on top of the workbench for a couple of days (where it rests on the sides and in the middle, the rest has air underneath it). While it has improved, it's not flat at all. Thanks for the suggestions